# Which are the recomended arguments to use when deleting a Collection within a Cloud Firestore database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using the following method to delete a Cloud Firestore collection as explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data).

```
deleteCollection(
    final CollectionReference collection,
    final int batchSize,
    Executor executor)
```

I have tried to use each one of the following three `Executors` and it works fine with which one of them.

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
```

Which one is recomended to be more efficient and used when calling `deleteCollection()` method? Or is there a better one?
What is the recommended `batchSize` we need to use to avoid out-of-memory errors?

Thnak you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sample code you see there for Android comes directly from [this code](https://github.com/firebase/snippets-android/blob/master/firestore/app/src/main/java/com/google/example/firestore/DocSnippets.java#L1016-L1069) in GitHub.  Digging around in there, you can see that the sample coded uses the following Executor:

```
private static final ThreadPoolExecutor EXECUTOR = new ThreadPoolExecutor(2, 4,
    60, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
```

Whether or not that's the best possible case for *your* particular situation, that's not really possible to say.

Regarding the batch size, the documentation also suggests that you need to make a judgement call:

> If you have larger collections, you may want to delete the documents
>   in smaller batches to avoid out-of-memory errors.

Given that we don't really know your specific situation, it's not really possible to give an answer that definitively gives you a best-possible solution.

Comment: Thanks for helping me again Doug! Voted up!